# Webpage button have no response after installing the Selenium IDE plugin

Tags: web-applications, selenium-ide

I have a javascript webapp, which is functional before I install the Selenium IDE plugin.

I would like to use Selenium IDE for testing. But after i installed the plugin. Even if I am not recording the script or running the script. I am unable to send request by clicking the "confirm" button. Given that the "confirm" button is within a pop-up message/window.

Tested all the same for Chrome, Edge and Firefox browser. All of them experencing the same issue. The button is back to normal and clickable after I turn off the IDE plugin.

Does anymore face this issue before?